# Creating half moon shaped background

Tags: html, css, background

For my Webpage I am trying to create a half moon shaped background. I am new to coding in general so my approach is probably all wrong, but I thought I could accomplish it with just editing my border radius. Do I have to do something majorly different to accomplish this? To be clear the background must be shaped into a half moon, so the exact opposite of what I am displaying with my code.

My code is formulated here:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600;626&display=swap');


/*  */ 
body {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
}


header {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px 10%;
    height:50px;
}

li, a {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:600px;
    color:black;
}

.Nav_links {
    list-style: none;
    height:0px;
}

.Nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.Nav_links li, a:hover {
    transition: 400ms;
    color:grey;
}

#Login_nav {
    display:block;
    align-items:center;
    height:15px;
}

.switchIconRotate {
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.fa-angle-down {
      color:#6161F2
}

.iconUp .fa-solid {
    transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
  
#Demobutton {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #4EC843;
    border-radius:34px;
    border:none;
    color: white;
    width:130px;
    height:35px;
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight:600px;
    font-size:14px;
}

#Demobutton:hover {
    background-color: #20D62C;
    transition:800ms;
  }

#Navbarline {
    display:block;
    width:80%;
    opacity:15%;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
    
}

section:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:75%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1565FF, #9FC0ff);
    border-top-right-radius: 510px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 510px;
    margin-left:auto;
    z-index:-1;
    
}
```

```html
 <body> 
        <section id="startingcolor">
        <header>
 <nav> 
                <ul class="Nav_links">
                    <li><a class="switch" href="#">Features <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down switchIconRotate"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>
            <div id="Login_nav">
        <a href="#">Login&ensp;</a> 
        <a href="#"><button id="Demobutton">Get demo</button></a> 
            </div>
        </header>
        <hr id="Navbarline"></hr>
        </section>


        <script src="/script.js"></script>
```

A picture of how it should look:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a semi circle. And where is it to sit in relation to the various bits of text?

Comment: The blue background should be displayed in a half moon shape, so basically now the blue background is pointing to the outside on the right, but I want it to point towards the center, which creates a moon shaped form.

Comment: A half moon is a semi circle so I am confused about what is required. Could you add a picture, a rough sketch will be fine.

Comment: I have added a picture of how it should look